# How to filter signals with non-uniform sampling rate?

Tags: filters, frequency-response

I have a digital signal that was made from analog one by staggering sampling rate:

$\tau_i = \begin{cases}\tau_{even}& \text{if } i = 2n\\
\tau_{odd} & \text{if } i = 2n+1\end{cases}$

And I have a simple correlative filter, for example, smoothing filter

```
[1, -2, 1]
```

**How should I calculate frequency response of such a filter?**

Comment: Has the analog signal been bandlimited before sampling?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but @Jdip answers it directly in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84232/55647) to [my related question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/83561/55647). I'll quote directly from his answer:

> [Digital Spectra Of Non-Uniformly Sampled Signals :  Theories and
> Applications](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10889) is a somewhat obscure reference (from 1988! can't go
> wrong!) that gives a general representation of the spectrum of a
> special case of non-uniformly sampled digital signals: **periodically
> non-uniform sampled signal**.

He continues with details from the paper:

> The paper deals with a special case of non-uniform sampling,
> **Periodically nonuniform sampling**, expanding on @Fats32’s [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83563/63763) regarding
>
> > sampling instants periodically repeated by blocks of $N$
>
> [image: Periodically nonuniform sampling]
>
> It starts with a signal $g(t)$, band-limited to ($-1/2T, 1/2T$), with
> Fourier transform $G^a(\omega)$:
>
> > The signal $g(t)$ is sampled in such a structured way that the sampling time instances [...] have an overall period $MT$.
>
> It then defines another band-limited sequence, $\bar{g}(t)$:
>
> > The sampled data sequence is then treated as if it were obtained by sampling another function $\bar{g}(t)$, [...] at uniform rate $1/T$.
>
> and states the aim of the paper (which answers your question, *at
> least for these types of non-uniformly sampled signals*):
>
> > We are interested in finding the representation of the digital spectrum of $\bar{g}(t)$ in terms of the Fourier transform
> > $G^a(\omega)$ of $g(t)$.
>
> Using the framework described above, it then goes through a really
> nice derivation of $G(\omega)$ to arrive at two representations, from
> which you can see the effect of the non-uniform sampling on the
> spectrum:
>
> $$G(\omega) = \frac{1}{MT}
>  \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\left[\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}G^a\left[\omega-k(\frac{2\pi}{MT})\right]e^{j[\omega-k(\frac{2\pi}{MT})]t_m}\right]e^{-jm\omega
>  T} \tag{2}$$
>
> And re-writing (2) with $t_m = mT - r_mT$, $r_m$ being the ratio of
> $mT - t_m$ to the average sampling period $T$ gives (4):
>
> $$G(\omega) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(
>  \frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}e^{-j\left[\omega-k(\frac{2\pi}{MT})\right]r_mT}e^{-jkm(\frac{2\pi}{M})}\right)G^a\left[\omega-k(\frac{2\pi}{MT})\right]
>  \tag{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

Relevant, [Synchrosqueezing-based Recovery of Instantaneous Frequency from Nonuniform Samples](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2533). The main result is that SSQ beats traditional bandlimited reconstruction approaches for a certain class of random sampling instant perturbations.

Filtering is achieved by manipulating the transform, followed by inversion. SSQ is implemented in Python at [ssqueezepy](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the class of random sampling perturbations that SSQ is better for?

Comment: @Gillespie [WGN?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qTxv.png). Not too familiar with the paper.