# What is the frequency representation of nonuniform sampling?

Tags: fourier-transform, sampling, frequency-domain, aliasing, nonuniform

Uniform sampling can be thought of as multiplication of a function $x(t)$ with a Dirac comb function: $$\text{III}_T(t) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-kT)$$

Multiplication of $x(t)$ with $\text{III}_T(t)$ is equivalent to convolution with $\text{III}_{1/T}(f) $ in the Fourier domain, giving rise to copies of $X(f)$ spaced by $\Delta f = 1/T$ (the well known sampling theorem):

$$x(t) \cdot \text{III}_T(t) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}}  \frac{1}{T} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} X(f-\frac{1}{T}k) $$

**Question:** What is the frequency representation of a ***non***-uniformly sampled $x(t)$? Or relatedly, what is the Fourier transform of a "non-uniform Dirac comb," assuming we know the time of each impulse?

The easy answer is that it is a sum of complex exponentials, but is there a way to simplify this, or see that it converges to a frequency domain Dirac comb as the time domain spacing approaches that of a uniform Dirac comb?

Many thanks for any insights!

### Edit

Perhaps it helps to focus on the issue of aliasing. What is the spacing and weighting of spectral copies of $X(f)$ for non-uniform sampling, if any? For uniform sampling, we know that spectral copies are uniformly weighted and spaced by $1/T$ as described above.

@Fat32 suggests in the comments on [his answer below](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83563/55647) that the copies are  spaced evenly at $k\Omega_s/N$ (where $\Omega_s$ = Nyquist sampling rate), but have unusual weights. Can anyone confirm this, and give insight into the weights?

Comment: You gotta scaling issue with $T$ that you might wanna worry about.  It's quite common and almost every electrical engineering text puts this $T$ in the passband gain of the reconstruction LPF, where it does not belong.

Comment: Could you elaborate Robert? Or do you have a link I could look at? Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Sure.  I wrote [several answers here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36774/while-converting-discrete-filter-specs-into-continuous-filter-specs-why-do-we-m/36777#36777) and have bitched for ***decades*** on *comp.dsp* about this issue, because nearly all EE DSP textbooks do it wrong.  They're mathematically good because they put this scaler $T$ into the passband gain of the reconstruction low-pass filter.

Comment: The strict mathematical point is that you gotta multiply $x(t)$ with $T\cdot \mathrm{III}_T(t)$ to get $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} X\big(f-\tfrac{k}{T} \big) $$ in the frequency domain.  If you leave that leading $T$ off in the dirac comb function, then you get an additional factor of $\frac1T$ in the frequency domain and most textbooks deal with that with a $T$ in the passband gain of the reconstruction filter **where it doesn't belong**.

Comment: Now, if your non-uniform sampling was sorta uniform in it's non-uniformity, then [this idea from Bob Adams](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78202/decimation-filter-that-throws-away-every-nth-sample-keeping-multiple-samples/78293#78293) shows that if you throw away one sample out of every $N$ samples, you can still get perfect reconstruction if your input $x(t)$ is bandlimited to a little lower than Nyquist: $$ X(f) = 0 \qquad \forall \ \ |f| \ge \frac{N-1}{N} \frac{1}{2T} $$ Remember $\frac{1}{T} = f_\mathrm{s}$ is the sampling frequency, so half of it is Nyquist.

Comment: I can't remember if I asked you this before, but are you Dan?

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the links. Any idea how this would translate to the nonuniform sampling case?

Comment: The Bob Adams thing was a **uniform** nonuniformity.  Every $N$th sample was dropped and from the samples remaining you could still get perfect reconstruction if the bandwidth of the input has been reduced proportionately.

Comment: I dunno how to do it for some other pattern of nonuniform sampling.

Comment: Also, no, not Dan :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be interested in this particular reference paper:

- [Digital Spectra Of Non-Uniformly Sampled Signals :
  Theories and Applications](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10889) is a somewhat obscure reference (from 1988! can't go wrong!) that gives a general representation of the spectrum of a special case of non-uniformly sampled digital signals: **periodically non-uniform sampled signal**. It's pretty convincing and a very interesting read, which I *think* answers part of your question.

Other references I found but didn't spend much time on:

- [Nonuniform sampling and spectral aliasing](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090780709001037?via%3Dihub), even though it doesn't really go into the math, it has some examples of aliasing frequency and weight which depend on the sampling scheme.
- [Aliasing in Spectrum of Non-uniformly Sampled Signals](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234047587_Aliasing_in_spectrum_of_nonuniformly_sampled_signals) has a lot more math, and seems to arrive at some formula but I admit I only grazed through that one.

---

**EDIT: Adding details for [the 1st reference](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10889)**

The paper deals with a special case of non-uniform sampling, **Periodically nonuniform sampling**, expanding on @Fats32’s [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/83563/63763) regarding

> sampling instants periodically repeated by blocks of $N$

[image: Periodically nonuniform sampling]

It starts with a signal $g(t)$, band-limited to ($-1/2T, 1/2T$), with Fourier transform $G^a(\omega)$:

> The signal $g(t)$ is sampled in such a structured way that the sampling time instances [...] have an overall period $MT$.

It then defines another band-limited sequence, $\bar{g}(t)$:

> The sampled data sequence is then treated as if it were obtained by sampling another function $\bar{g}(t)$, [...] at uniform rate $1/T$.

and states the aim of the paper (which answers your question, *at least for these types of non-uniformly sampled signals*):

> We are interested in finding the representation of the digital spectrum of $\bar{g}(t)$ in terms of the Fourier transform $G^a(\omega)$ of $g(t)$.

Using the framework described above, it then goes through a really nice derivation of $G(\omega)$ to arrive at two representations, from which you can see the effect of the non-uniform sampling on the spectrum:

$$G(\omega) = \frac{1}{MT} \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\left[\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}G^a\left[\omega-k(\frac{2\pi}{MT})\right]e^{j[\omega-k(\frac{2\pi}{MT})]t_m}\right]e^{-jm\omega T} \tag{2}$$

And re-writing (2) with $t_m = mT - r_mT$, $r_m$ being the ratio of $mT - t_m$ to the average sampling period $T$ gives (4):

$$G(\omega) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{M}\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}e^{-j\left[\omega-k(\frac{2\pi}{MT})\right]r_mT}e^{-jkm(\frac{2\pi}{M})}\right)G^a\left[\omega-k(\frac{2\pi}{MT})\right] \tag{4}$$

Comment: May I suggest you to use links for papers that are more perennial and informative. For the first paper, a DOI could work: [dx.doi.org/10.1109/imtc.1988.10889](dx.doi.org/10.1109/imtc.1988.10889). There, one gets more bibliographic information, etc.

Comment: @LaurentDuval I will gladly accept your suggestion, but how do I turn it into a link?

Comment: Once you get the DOI, through web search,  happen dx.doi.org/ before

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jdip! That first paper in particular looks promising. I will look into it some more myself, but if you can add the relevant details and equations to your answer, it would be much appreciated. I think this is close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Gillespie, I doubt you'll find a **general** closed-form representation of the spectrum of non-uniformly sampled signals, but I added a brief summary of the 1st reference that describes a particular sampling scheme: *periodically non-uniform sampling*. Hope this is somewhat what you were looking for!

Comment: @LaurentDuval done! Thanks!

Comment: @Jdip, I'm thinking the result *might* hold if we choose a repetition period M (of the nonuniform sequence) equal to the length of the entire signal. Thus, no true repetition of the nonuniform sampling within the length of the signal, but assumed repetition of the signal and its sampling scheme. What do you think of that? I'm not able to dive in just now, but I'll look at it more later today.

Comment: @Gillespie I have to think about that. I'm not sure I completely understand the reasoning behind that statement, but I also have to admit I might be a little out of my depth here! When I have more time I'll dig in the math a more as well. Very interesting stuff!

Comment: @Jdip, I've submitted some minor edits to the equations. There was a missing $j$ in the first one, and missing division signs (by $MT$ and $M$) in the second which were hard to read, but I think I can see them in the paper, and confirmed they should be there by careful derivation. 

Also, I took the liberty of re-numbering the equations to the numbering they have in the paper (2 & 4). It's your answer, so feel free to revert if you prefer!

Comment: @Gillespie Thanks for the edits! I wanted to rename the equations actually and forgot so thank you for that as well ;)

Comment: The interesting thing would be to simulate these equations in MATLAB. I'll get to that eventually...

Comment: @Gillespie I had started doing that and got side-tracked by work. When I get a chance I'll get back to it

Comment: I will look forward to that.

Answer (score 2):

For the simplest case of $N$ random samples of $x(t)$ taken over a duration of $T$ and satisfying the average Nyquist rate criterion, then the resulting Fourier transform of the non-uniform samples will be an $N$-fold aliased (as if $N$ times undersampled) and weighted sum of $X(\Omega)$.

This is an approximate statement which would be ideally true if the sampling instants periodically repeated by blocks of $N$, an ideal situation. If this is not so; i.e., random sampling instants never repeat or do not extend from minus to plus infinity, or if there's no analytic expression for the non-uniform sampling instants, then a closed form expression for the Fourier transform of the non-uniform samples may not exist. (I cannot say it won't, but I think it won't)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Fat32. If the sampling is random, but we know where the samples were taken, can we say anything about how the aliasing occurs? Like where the wrapping point is for the ailaised copy of the spectrum for a given sample or something like that (if that even makes sense)? Also, what do you mean by "sampling instants periodically repeated by blocks of N"? Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @Gillespie yes that's the most typical scenerio. Aliasing will be similar to that of undersampling by N, but with special weights. Repeating is to make finite length samples go to infinity for mathematical convenience.

Comment: Correct me if I'm misunderstanding, but if taking N random samples produces N-fold aliasing, that would be similar (in some sense) to taking N/N = 1 sample, which doesn't make sense. I must be missing something. Can you illustrate what you're talking about?

Comment: @Gillespie you are right in your misunderstanding because the term *N-fold alising* was very loose. What I wanted to say was that if the original Nyquist Sampling Rate is $\Omega_s$ then the aliased copies of $X(\Omega)$ will be shifted by $\Omega_s / N$ which would create N times overlapping copies to be added through the band $[0,\Omega_s]$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are you saying that *all* N of the aliased copies are centered at $\Omega_s/N$?

Comment: @Gillespie No. They are centered at $k \Omega_s/N$ to right; that's why I miscoined the term *N-fold alias* :-)

Comment: Got it, thanks! Is there a formula for the scaling/weighting of the aliased copies?

Comment: @Gillespie yes there's. Indeed nonuniform to uniform conversion packages should be using that (or a similar) formula...

Comment: Well, one of the reasons I posted this question in the first place is because I can't find this formula, though I've searched high and low. Do you have a reference you could point me to?

Comment: @Gillespie If you have access to *ieeexplore* , then I suggest you search the papers "nonuniform sampling" from the authors, "JL Yen, and Oppenheim" . They have some papers that can guide you...

Answer (score 2):

If the samples are finite (e.g. not a running process) then you'd have to take the greatest common divider and resample all the vector, resulting in a "toothless" train of impulses.

For example, suppose the vector is $x=[1, 2, 1, 3]$ and it's sampled at $t=[0, 3, 5, 10]$. The time derivative will be $t'=[3, 2, 5]$, showing the step sizes. This means that the maximum sample size that would satisfy equisampling would be $T=1$, in which case the resulting vector will look like this: $y=[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]$. This is as "analytic" as you can get.

If $x$ is a live signal then the only thing you can do is to use chunks of the signal and perform an FFT on them as above, but any subsequent difference will mean that the first FFT will not be the same as any of the following chunks.

Comment: It looks like [@Jdip's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/84232/17189) (+1) is the one you're looking for, but I still think it's a mission impossible given that you have missing possible information. E.g. in my example, between 1 and 2 there are two unknowns. Actually, I realize that I left it at a train of impulses, but it should be filled -- and that's the unknown, there's no information on *how* to fill. Will it be linear/cubic/spline/etc? Simply saying that the signal is band-limited is not enough. Filling with Dirac can be done in infinite ways in-between, bandwidth will be obeyed.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab has the [`nufft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.nufft.html) which uses:

> For a vector $X$ of length $n$, sample points $t$, and frequencies
> $f$, the nonuniform discrete Fourier transform of $X$ is defined as
>
> $$Y(k)= \sum_{j=1}^{n} X(j)e^{−2\pi i t(j) f(k)}$$
>
> where $k = 1, 2, \ldots, m$. When $t = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$ and $f = (0,
> > 1, \ldots, n-1)/n$ (defaults for `nufft`), the formula is equivalent
> to the uniform discrete Fourier transform used by the `fft` function.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, I'm aware that the non-uniform DFT can be calculated, but I'm more interested in the principle behind non-uniform sampling. For example, aliasing manifests differently for non-uniform sampling. Rather than perfect replicas that overlap and sum in the frequency domain (as in uniform sampling), you get some kind of mishmash with non-uniform sampling that it seems like we should be able to describe mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

There's some analog non-uniform sampling theory and before microchips took over signal processing there were analog systems around to obtain the spectrum of non-uniformly sampled signals.

Analog signal processing is still active in some applications, actually [this IET recent event](https://events.theiet.org/events/ieee-distinguished-lecture-new-opportunities-in-non-uniform-sampling-co-organized-by-iet-malaysia-network/) mentions a shy revival of analog processing.

But the point is, it all ends up being processed with a CPU or GPU and unless you are doing Quantum processing research or developing a new analog processing computer, you have to work with one discrete sequence of numbers.

It's far more practical and common practice to 1st 'resample' the signal into a regular time interval dt and then apply for instance FFT.

1.- Import the signal and time reference into MATLAB

2.- Try this

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/resampling-nonuniformly-sampled-signals.html?s_tid=srchtitle_non-uniform%20sampling_1

3.- Unless the signal has really dispare time intervals, like a cluster of many samples pretty close each other with really low dt, followed by eons of time to next cluster, then it may be the case that some interpolation sufices to turn it into a quite 'regular' time interval signal.

You can do different 'resamplings' and measure coherence among obtained spectrums.

4.- If you supply the signal or a significant chunk of it I may be able to further help with MATLAB, free of charge, I like solving problems with MATLAB.

Awaiting answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. Perhaps I wasn't quite clear in my question, but I'm more interested in the precise mathematical effects of nonuniform sampling. I know you can resample to a uniform grid, but this process leaves artifacts unless you try to account for them.